# Core data - relational entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, relationship

I have three entities - teacher, class, subject. I have subjects, which are teaches in school for example it are only: math,biology, english. This subjects can be teaches at many classes - english in 7.A, 4.C, 3.D math in 3.D, 2.D, 1.D etc. And teachers teaches at many classes and the can also teaches many subjects for example math at 2.D, 3.D and biology at 4.C, 3.A. I need information WHO,WHERE and WHAT teaches so I have to answer this questions WHO teaches math (WHAT) in 3.D (WHERE). And I don't know how to model the Core data model. Could you give me a advise please? I used to work with ERD and I know it is little bit different. If I work with for example mySQL I'll  use a one extra relational entity, which will have a three columns: teacher,subject, class and has relations N:1 with tables: teacher,subject, class. Its necessary when I work with Core Data? How have to it solve?

Answer (score 0):

You would do the same thing in Core Data.  You would create a join entity that has a relationship to teacher, class and subject.  That entity could have additional information of time, level, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus is not quite right.Core Data creates the join entities for you "under the covers". You just specify a many-to-many relationship which comes back as an NSSet on each object. If you peek inside the SQLite you'll see the table with the relationships is created and maintained for you. If you create one to many relationships, the extra table is not needed.
In your example I am not sure you even need the extra table though. I think class->teacher is one to one, class->subject is one to one, and teacher->subject is a query that effectively does a JOIN.